# jq - select objects with given key name

Tags: json, jq

I've got an arbitrary structure with many levels, etc. I need to select all objects that contain a key named `updateDate`. How do I do that with jq? I came up with one way but it also produces errors on invalid data types when it visits a leaf which I have to grep out:

```
jq 'recurse(.[]) | has("updateDate")' | grep -Fv error
```

I don't really understand how to also check for types or leaves and I suspect there is a simpler way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In 1.4 you can just:

```
jq '..|.updateDate?'
```

If you're stuck with 1.3 you can use a longer program like so:

```
jq 'recurse(if type == "array" or type = "object" then .[] else empty end) | if type == "object" then .updateDate else empty end'
```

Comment: This will error out when the structure includes arrays. Adding `|objects|` in the middle fixes it, I think.

Comment: Note if you want to filter empty arrays then you could follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196653/308851 `jq '..|.updateDate?|select(length>0)'`

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer also produces `null` for every object that **doesn't** have the key.

What worked for me was:

```
jq '..|objects|.updateDate//empty'
```

The `.updateDate//empty` part means: if `.updateDate` is `null` (or `false`), skip it entirely.

This of course wouldn't work if you expect your key to have values of `false` or `null`. In that case, use this:

```
jq '..|objects|select(has("updateDate"))|.updateDate'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested: how about `jq 'recurse(.[]?) | objects | has("updateDate")'` ?

Comment: recurse(.[]?) | objects | select(has("a"))