# Remove all null values

Tags: json, bash, null, jq

I am trying to remove null values from a json object using jq. I found [this issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/104) on their github and so now I'm trying to remove them with `del`.
I have this:

```
'{ id: $customerId, name, phones: ([{ original: .phone }, 
 { original: .otherPhone}]), email} | del(. | nulls)'
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. However if I replace `nulls` with `.phones` it does remove the phone numbers.

Comment: Please extend this to be complete enough to run, showing input, actual output, and desired output. (For instance, you could provide minimal JSON input in a heredoc, by running `jq '...your code here...' <<'EOF'`, including some JSON that demonstrates the problem, and having an `EOF` afterwards). See also [the Help Center documentation on Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ...as it is, it's hard to tell where in your data structure the NULs actually are, which is critical to being able to build or test a solution.

Comment: Note that while I'm voting to close the question as it's currently written, (1) it won't actually be closed unless others agree, and (2) editing a closed question automatically puts it into a queue to be considered for reopening, so extending it to include a MCVE should result in that closure being reversed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Regarding your comment about "NULs" -- (1) the OP was asking about JSON "null", not "NUL"; (2) to anyone who knows jq, it's clear where the nulls are; (3) to anyone who knows JSON, it's fairly obvious.

Comment: @peak, it's not obvious to me without following the github link to see the data at hand, and questions that only make sense when given out-of-band content are explicitly incomplete here -- that's *extremely* well-settled on meta, hence, my request for *actual input* to be included in the question itself. Yes, one could also edit the input data into the question itself -- either of us does that and there's no more grounds for disagreement. That said, asking the OP to do so themselves has the benefit of making it less likely they'll make the same mistake again in the future.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following illustrates how to remove all the null-valued keys from a JSON object:

```
jq -n '{"a":1, "b": null, "c": null} | with_entries( select( .value != null ) )'
{
  "a": 1
}
```

Alternatively, `paths/0` can be used as follows:

```
. as $o | [paths[] | {(.) : ($o[.])} ] | add
```

By the way, `del/1` can also be used to achieve the same result, e.g. using this filter:

```
reduce keys[] as $k (.; if .[$k] == null then del(.[$k]) else . end)
```

Or less obviously, but more succinctly:

```
del( .[ (keys - [paths[]])[] ] )
```

And for the record, here are two ways to use `delpaths/1`:

```
jq -n '{"a":1, "b": null, "c": null, "d":2} as $o
  | $o
  | delpaths( [  keys[] | select( $o[.] == null ) ] | map( [.]) )'


$ jq -n '{"a":1, "b": null, "c": null, "d":2}
  | [delpaths((keys - paths) | map([.])) ] | add'
```

In both these last two cases, the output is the same:
{
"a": 1,
"d": 2
}

---

For reference, if you wanted to remove null-valued keys from all JSON objects in a JSON text (i.e., recursively), you could use `walk/1`, or:

```
del(.. | objects | (to_entries[] | select(.value==null) | .key) as $k | .[$k])
```

Comment: What is meant by `/1` in the references to functions like `del/1`?  I've seen it in other answers here, too, but not in jq's documentation.

Comment: It is the arity of the function. The most recent versions of jq have a builtin named `builtins` which emits an array of strings of the form FUNCTOR/ARITY

Answer (score 37):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654730) by [Michael Homer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73093/michael-homer) on https://unix.stackexchange.com has a super concinse solution which works since jq 1.6:

```
del(..|nulls)
```

It deletes all null-valued properties (and values) from your JSON. Simple and sweet :)

`nulls` is a builtin filter and can be replaced by custom selects:

```
del(..|select(. == "value to delete"))
```

To remove elements based on multiple conditions, e.g. remove all bools and all numbers:

```
del(..|booleans,numbers)
```

or, to only delete nodes not matching a condition:

```
del(..|select(. == "value to keep" | not))
```

(The last example is only illustrative – of course you could swap `==` for `!=`, but sometimes this is not possible. e.g. to *keep* all truthy values: `del(..|select(.|not))`)

Comment: And comments under the linked answer suggest to use `jq 'del(recurse(.[]?;true)|select(. == null))'` for version 1.5, which I used successfully.

Answer (score 8):

All the other answers to date here are workarounds for old versions of `jq`, and it isn't clear how do do this simply in the latest released version. In JQ 1.6 or newer this will do the job to remove nulls recursively:

```sh
$ jq 'walk( if type == "object" then with_entries(select(.value != null)) else . end)' input.json
```

Sourced from [this comment](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/104#issuecomment-289637207) on the issue where adding the `walk()` function was discussed upstream.

Answer (score 5):

[WARNING: the definition of `walk/1` given in this response is problematic, not least for the reason given in the first comment; note also that jq 1.6 defines `walk/1` differently.]

I am adding the new answer to emphasize the extended version of the script by @jeff-mercado. My version of the script assumes the empty values are as follows:

- `null`;
- `[]` - empty arrays;
- `{}` - empty objects.

Removing of empty arrays and objects was borrowed from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196653/3627676.

```
def walk(f):
    . as $in | 
    if type == "object" then
        reduce keys[] as $key
            ( {}; . + { ($key): ( $in[$key] | walk(f) ) } ) | f
    elif type == "array" then 
        select(length > 0) | map( walk(f) ) | f
    else 
        f
    end;

walk(
    if type == "object" then
        with_entries(select( .value != null and .value != {} and .value != [] ))
    elif type == "array" then
        map(select( . != null and . != {} and .!= [] ))
    else
        .
    end
)
```

Comment: Adding `select(length > 0) |` to `def walk(f)` is a mistake.  For some JSON, it removes non-empty arrays.  For other JSON (e.g., nested objects, each including some nulls and empty structures), only `{}` was returned.  However, the condition shown here works with the original definition of `walk`.  I just noticed this problem, so I can't change the vote I gave yesterday.

Comment: The more elegant solution by the following link https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/104#issuecomment-707806841

Answer (score 3):

That's not what `del/1` was meant to be used for.  Given an object as input, if you wanted to remove the `.phones` property, you'd do:

```
del(.phones)
```

In other words, the parameter to `del` is the path to the property you wish to remove.

If you wanted to use this, you would have to figure out all the paths to `null` values and pass it in to this.  That would be more of a hassle though.

---

Streaming the input in could make this task even simpler.

```
fromstream(tostream | select(length == 1 or .[1] != null))
```

---

Otherwise for a more straightforward approach, you'll have to walk through the object tree to find `null` values.  If found, filter it out.  Using `walk/1`, your filter could be applied recursively to exclude the `null` values.

```
walk(
    (objects | with_entries(select(.value != null)))
    // (arrays | map(select(. != null)))
    // values
)
```

So if you had this for input:

```
{
    "foo": null,
    "bar": "bar",
    "biz": [1,2,3,4,null],
    "baz": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": null,
        "c": ["a","b","c","null",32,null]
    }
}
```

This filter would yield:

```
{
    "bar": "bar",
    "baz": {
        "a": 1,
        "c": ["a","b","c","null",32]
    },
    "biz": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Comment: Jeff - First, using walk, you can just write: walk( if type == "object" then with_entries( select(.value != null) ) elif type == "array" then map(select(. != null)) else . end).  Second, walk/1 is already available in the development version.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't realize it went depth first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Elsewhere on this page, some interest has been expressed in
using jq to eliminate recursively occurrences of [] and {} as well as null.

Although it is possible to use the built-in definition of `walk/1` to do
this, it is a bit tricky to do so correctly.  Here therefore is a variant version
of `walk/1` which makes it trivial to do so:

```
def traverse(f):
  if type == "object" then map_values(traverse(f)) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( traverse(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;
```

In order to make it easy to modify the criterion for removing elements, 
we define:

```
def isempty: .==null or ((type|(.=="array" or .=="object")) and length==0);
```

The solution is now simply:

```
traverse(select(isempty|not))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### With newer versions of jq (1.6 and later)

You can use this expression to remove null-valued keys recursively:

```
jq 'walk( if type == "object" then with_entries(select(.value != null)) else . end)'
```

[REF](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/104#issuecomment-289637207)

Comment: This answer is identical to [Caleb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58022572/112968) posted 1 year earlier?

Answer (score 0):

[WARNING: the response below has several problems, not least those arising from the fact that `0|length` is 0.]

Elaborating on an [earlier answer](/q/39500608/39501114#39501114), in addition to removing properties with `null` values, it's often helpful to remove JSON properties with empty array or object values (i.e., `[]` or `{}`), too.

> ℹ️ — jq's `walk()` function (`walk/1`) makes this easy.  `walk()` will be
>   available in a future version of jq (> `jq-1.5`), but [its
>   definition](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L284)
>   can be added to current filters.

The condition to pass to `walk()` for removing nulls and empty structures is:

```
walk(
  if type == "object" then with_entries(select(.value|length > 0))
  elif type == "array" then map(select(length > 0))
  else .
  end
)
```

Given this JSON input:

```
{
  "notNullA": "notNullA",
  "nullA": null,
  "objectA": {
    "notNullB": "notNullB",
    "nullB": null,
    "objectB": {
      "notNullC": "notNullC",
      "nullC": null
    },
    "emptyObjectB": {},
    "arrayB": [
      "b"
    ],
    "emptyBrrayB": []
  },
  "emptyObjectA": {},
  "arrayA": [
    "a"
  ],
  "emptyArrayA": []
}
```

Using this function gives the result:

```
{
  "notNullA": "notNullA",
  "objectA": {
    "notNullB": "notNullB",
    "objectB": {
      "notNullC": "notNullC"
    },
    "arrayB": [
      "b"
    ]
  },
  "arrayA": [
    "a"
  ]
}
```