# How to merge two JSON files using jq or any tool?

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I've got 2 json files and want to merge them into one file.
Here the content of files:

a.json:

```
{
    "config":
    {
        "config1":
        {
            "config11":
            {
                "apple":"apple",
                "orange":"orange",
                "lemon":[
                    "lemon1",
                    "lemon2",
                    "lemon3"
                ],
                "pear":"pear"
            }
        },
        "config2":
        {
            "config21":"hello",
            "config22":"goodbye"
        }
    }
}
```

b.json:

```
{
    "config":
    {
        "config1":
        {
            "config11":
            {
                "apple":null,
                "orange":null,
                "lemon":[
                    "lemon4",
                    "lemon5",
                    "lemon6"
                ],
                "pear":null
            }
        },
        "config2":
        {
            "config21":"hey",
            "config22":null
        }
    }
}
```

I want to merge the not-null part of b.json into a.json

Expected result:

```
{
    "config":
    {
        "config1":
        {
            "config11":
            {
                "apple":"apple",
                "orange":"orange",
                "lemon":[
                    "lemon4",
                    "lemon5",
                    "lemon6"
                ],
                "pear":"pear"
            }
        },
        "config2":
        {
            "config21":"hey",
            "config22":"goodbye"
        }
    }
}
```

I try this command:

```
jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' a.json b.json
```

but the output is not i want

i read https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual ,but i still don't know how to do

Any helps？Thank you.

**append**:

aa.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "config_again": {
      "country": {
        "countrylist": [
          "CANADA",
          "MEXICO",
          "USA"
        ]
      },
      "language": {
        "languageorderlist": [
          "en_US",
          "hu_HU",
          "in_ID",
          "it_IT",
          "iw_IL",
          "zh_CN"
        ]
      },
      "video": {
        "mp4": "1",
        "mkv": "1"
      },
      "Audio": {
        "audio_audio": "0x111111"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

bb.json:

```
{
  "config": {
    "config_again": {
      "country": {
        "countrylist": [
          "USA"
        ]
      },
      "language": {
        "languageorderlist": [
          "en_US",
          "de_DE"
        ]
      },
      "video": {
        "mp4": null,
        "mkv": null
      },
      "Audio": {
        "audio_audio": "0x666666"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The key to a simple solution here is using `paths`, `getpath`, and `setpath`, e.g. like so:

#### Invocation

```
jq -f program.jq --argfile b b.json a.json
```

#### program.jq

```
reduce ($b | paths(scalars)) as $p (.;
  ($b|getpath($p)) as $v
  | if $v != null then setpath($p; $v) else . end)
```

Comment: You've spent more time looking at it than I have -- is this actually a distinct, non-duplicative question? (At a glance I'm not seeing the distinguishing factors).

Comment: Good question, but I was not optimistic that I could find it without wasting quite a lot of time ....

Comment: Hmm. Looking a little closer, I'd argue that it could be close with _two_ duplicates, [remove all null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500608/remove-all-null-values) and [How to merge 2 json objects from 2 files using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-objects-from-2-files-using-jq), but while combining the two answers would work, the end result would not be as clean as what you're doing here, so there's value to keeping it open.

Comment: Thanks.
but in this case( i add another two json files aa.json and bb.json), `jq -f program.jq --argfile b bb.json aa.json`, it doesn't work. I can't figure out the reason.
i found another way:[Merging JSON files recursively in the command-line](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/merging-json-files-recursively-in-the-command-line/)

Answer (score 1):

[Merging JSON files recursively in the command-line](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/merging-json-files-recursively-in-the-command-line/)

deepmerge.jq:

```
def deepmerge(a;b):                                                                                                                                                  
    reduce b[] as $item (a; 
        reduce ($item | keys_unsorted[]) as $key (.; 
            $item[$key] as $val | ($val | type) as $type | .[$key] = if ($type == "object") then
            deepmerge({}; [if .[$key] == null then {} else .[$key] end, $val])
            elif ($type == "null") then
            .[$key]
            else
            $val
            end)
        );   
    deepmerge({}; .)
```

```
jq -f deepmerge.jq -s aa.json bb.json
```

it works