# jq select where property contains property by name

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I have a basic JSON structure:

```json
{
  "A": {
    "Option1": {
      "contains": {
         "inner1": { ... },
         "inner2": { ... },
         "innerN": { ... }
      }
    }

    "Option2": {
         "innerX": { ... },
         "innerY": { ... },
         "innerZ": { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

What I need is to select either `Option1` or `Option2` based on whether or not it contains user input.

For example:

- If the user provides `inner1`, return the `Option1` object
- If the user provides `innerY` return the `Option2` object
- etc.

I have been successful if the options were an array, but I cannot do this if they are objects themselves.

I tried looking at [this example using `descend`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946092/how-to-recurse-with-jq-on-nested-json-where-each-object-has-a-name-property) but didn't quite follow.

---

### Update 1

I got a sloppy means to do this and then reuse the expression:

```sh
jq -r 'paths | select(.[-1] == "inner1") | .[0:-2] | join(".")' myFile.json
```

I can store that in a variable and reuse it. But that seems sloppy. It's a workaround, though.

To test that out I did this:

```sh
jq .$(THAT_COMMAND_ABOVE) myFile.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your approach, the jq `filter` you'd need is `getpath`:

```
getpath(paths | select(.[-1] == "inner1") | .[0:-2])
```

As an alternative, you could also use `..`, e.g. perhaps:

```
.. | objects | map_values( select(has("inner1"))) | select(length>0)
```

Comment: Got it! I was missing a couple pieces of syntax. I think I needed something specific to my needs to drive some of those concepts home. Much appreciated.