# Is there a way to query a nested value in jmespath without having to provide the path?

Tags: jmespath

I'm trying to find a way to get all the names from the people list, without have to specify the path. Is there a way to do this in JMESPath. i.e without having to step down multiple paths.
I.e.: I want to grab a list of all the names.

```json
{
  "country": {
    "people": [
      {
        "age": 20,
        "name": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "age": 25,
        "name": "Fred"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In the world of JSONata this would be:

```
**.name

# which would give you ...
[
  "Bob",
  "Fred"
]
```

Based on: [jmespath how do I find the key values in the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71345286/jmespath-how-do-i-find-the-key-values-in-the-dictionary) it appears this cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

In the world of JmesPath this is `'*[].name'`. For example, given the file

```json
shell> cat people.json 
{
    "people": [
        {
            "age": 20,
            "name": "Bob"
        },
        {
            "age": 25,
            "name": "Fred"
        }
    ]
}
```

```py
>>> import json
>>> import jmespath
>>> f = open('people.json')
>>> data = json.load(f)
>>> f.close()
>>> jmespath.search('*[].name', data)
['Bob', 'Fred']
```

Comment: Did you know that you do not need to go in such a burden to create a Python program in order to tests those? The JMESPath homepage is a playground for quarries, just replace the query and input in the respective boxes and the result will adapt.